# How to deal with a question whose answer changed through time?

Tags: discussion, time

Some time ago, I answered this question :

[Java 8 options for AIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994778/java-8-options-for-aix)

At that time (sept. 2014) there was no official release of Java SDK 8 for AIX. But now there is (since march 2015).

I already did a '*late edit*', see my answer, but I don't find this ideal.
I'm confused on what should be done to have a real quality answer:

1. Rollback my answer without the 'late edit' => Leave it to its "initial time context"
2. Rewrite completely the answer because, if I were to answer it today, I would not say what I said before (since Java SDK 8 for AIX exists) => Loose the "initial time context".
3. Leave it as-is.

My question/problem is really:

**How should an answer match the *time context* of the question?**

And to focus an the rewriting:

**Should we rewrite an answer that is no longer valid?**

For information, my answer (which is the only answer suggested) was not choosen by the OP.

Comment: You could also add another answer that's relevant "as of now".

Comment: Isn't this at least one of the reason that resource/library requests are usually considered off-topic?  While this one might not tend to attract spam, it has the issue that the answers get stale and outdated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Firstly, you might find this question on MSE relevant; [How to deal with obsolete answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11705/how-to-deal-with-obsolete-answers).

Personally, I've come across this quite a bit with my own answers, and generally do exactly what you just did; [here's one particular example of an edit I made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768183/click-event-not-working-in-jquery/7768207#7768207).

One stylistic point I'd like to mention though; "storyline edits" look messy, and often make the post harder to read. I prefer editing posts so they read;

> Before version X, you could do...
>
> As of version X.1 however, you can now do...

One thing I *definitely* wouldn't do is completely re-write the answer; there may be people out there *stuck* on older versions of software, for which your older answer was *entirely* applicable to. It's also pretty bad form (in my eyes) to fundamentally re-write answers for which you've accrued upvotes, and even accepts.

Comment: This case seems tricky to me as the previous answer said "there is no released version, a beta exists" and now it is just "the versions exist and is available here". So the interest of the old answer is really limited now, isn't it? Thanks for the links, I'll look into it. BTW, good luck for the elections ;)

Comment: @superbob: Humm, add in the fact the link to the beta no longer works, and I'm beginning to see the dilemma! Since I can't see the old answer being useful to *anyone*, it may be better to re-write the answer. I did this before when the Twitter API I was writing for got removed completely; http://stackoverflow.com/a/8836998/444991. P.S: Thanks ;).

Comment: I think the answer is a "_it depends_" as it is difficult to have rule that is always relevant. In the general case I would come up with what you or @amit suggested, but sometimes a complete or partial rewrite is better.

Comment: In the end I realized that I didn't had to "rewrite completely" to be relevant, so I removed the irrelevant parts a updated the answer to look as close as possible to its initial state. I added like a "footnote" to explain the differences with the initial version. I took this liberty because there were not a lot of comments and the answer wasn't accepted.

Answer (score 5):

I think there are already thousands of answers on SO which have already crossed their age and have become invalid. While visiting answers I also  read the time it was posted and that certainly clears lot of things.

I think best you can do is to append the new answer (as if you would answer it today) as an edit to the existing answer. Changing the answer completely will have cascading effect like some comments if exist will also become obsolete.

Comment: I like the idea, why not prepend, so the "new" answer is seen first (with a leading bold statement like "Update answer 04/2015:" and putting the "old" answer after a statement like "Old answer 06/2014:"

Comment: @superbob, Exactly that is the best option we have.. Many users have already started doing this.